# Windows 7, entering BIOS fails (I CAN boot to it, but nothing happens)

Tags: windows-7, bios

Primers:

- System specs at bottom
- Fast boot is disabled.
- In msconfig, "noGUIboot" is not checked
- **I have a direct-to-BIOS executable**

Entering the BIOS stalls, or perhaps succeeds but doesn't display. The monitor goes to "no connection detected," as if my PC is fully turned off, and just stays like that. I have to hard reset. I tried using my direct-to-BIOS option twice, then attempted conventionally with an F2 spam after doing a normal shutdown. It always results in my PC restarting and then the monitor going blank.

Incidentally, even though I **do** have fast boot disabled, the "boot to BIOS" menu never displays on a normal startup. But, I should clarify, that's not my main issue, though it may be related.

Personally I'm inclined to think this might be a GPU issue of not being able to display the BIOS. The whole reason I'm trying to access it is to switch over to CPU while troubleshooting my GPU. My resolution got reduced to 800x640, the "adjust resolution" option in the control panel is locked, and a driver update+restart fixed nothing. Is it possible that I'm successfully booting to BIOS and the GPU just isn't showing it?

**Specs:**

Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601)

System Manufacturer: ASUS

System Model: All Series

BIOS: BIOS Date: 02/24/15 20:27:24 Ver: 24.01

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz (8 CPUs), ~4.0GHz

Memory: 32768MB RAM

Available OS Memory: 32710MB RAM

DirectX Version: DirectX 11

Comment: Go you have a discrete GPU installed, or are you running onboard? If you're running discrete, can you remove it and connect to an onboard display output? If you don't have that option, can you connect a different GPU temporarily? Have you deleted the GPU from Device Manager?

Comment: Thank you. It is a separate card, which I should have known to check since it's a recent addition to my setup. All I had to do was switch the HDMI from the card to the motherboard.

Comment: You don't need to edit your post title to indicate solution. Just mark the appropriate answer when it is posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain combinations of BIOS and discrete GPU do not support displaying the BIOS through the discrete GPU.

In situations like these, in order to view the BIOS UI you must connect your display to the onboard video output rather than the video outputs of the discrete GPU.

Some, but not all of these BIOS have settings that control this function and if so, you can set this setting and view the BIOS UI while still connected to the discrete GPU's outputs.